# Is there another way to access an *ngFor item other than by its index

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an `*ngFor` list of food items (`foods`) that performs an animation when the user mouses over the element

```
<div [@foodState]="food.state" *ngFor="let food of foods; trackBy let i=index" (mouseenter)="open(i)" (mouseleave)="close(i)">
```

The `open()` and `close()` methods alter a property on the element called `state`

```
open(i: number): void{
  this.foods[i].state = 'open';
}
```

which triggers a new animation state

```
animations: [
  trigger('foodState', [
    state('closed', style({
      height: '36px'
    })),
    state('open', style({
      height: '58px'
    })),
  ])
]
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want to add a `@Pipe` to filter the data based on a search term:

```
<div [@foodState]="food.state" *ngFor="let food of foods| searchPipe: searchTerm; trackBy let i=index" (mouseenter)="open(i)" (mouseleave)="close(i)">
```

the `@Pipe` transforms the `foods` list using the `filter()` function:

```
transform(foods: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {
  foods = foods.filter(food => food.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toUpperCase()) !== -1 );
  return foods;
}
```

so now the index of the food, over which the user will hover, no longer corresponds to the correct food in the `foods` list.

**Is there a way to trigger the state of a repeated item without accessing it through its original array index? Or is there another way that I should approach accessing data in `*ngFor` lists?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the food item itself instead of just the index:

```
 <div [@foodState]="food.state" *ngFor="let food of foods; trackBy let i=index" (mouseenter)="open(food)" (mouseleave)="close(food)">
```

and change the open and close methods as well:

```
open(food: any): void{
  food.state = 'open';
}
```